Corollary to the Three Series Theorem
Problem
Suppose $X, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are iid and in $L^p$ for some $1 < p < 2$. Show that the series of $Y_n=\frac{X_n − \mathbb{E}(X)}{n^{1/p}}$ converges.
Partial solution
Here, we do not have variance, which rules out the use of Khintchine-Kolmogorov Convergence Theorem. We then move on to the necessary and sufficient Kolmogorov 3 Series Theorem. I cannot really understand how to verify these, though, as for example
$$
\sum \mathbb{P}(|Y_k|>1)= \sum \mathbb{P}(|X_k - \mathbb{E}[X]|> n^{1/p}) \leq \sum \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])] \frac{1}{n}
$$
where I have used Chebychev with $g(x) = x^p$ (there is not much else that comes to my mind), and where the right hand side obviously diverges. What kind of upper bound could I use here (and in the other 2 series) to ensure convergence?

What do you mean by "series of $Y_n$"? Is it $\sum_n Y_n$?

Yep that is it :)

Note. This is not a full answer. I'm able to check the first condition. The third condition is using a lemma from a book I read. I have not yet verified the second condition.
WLOG we assume $\mathbb{E}X = \mathbb{E}X_n = 0 \ \forall n$. Fixed $A > 0$. For the first condition, we have
$$
    \begin{align*}
      \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\vert Y_k \vert > A) &= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\vert X_k \vert > Ak^{1/p})\\
    &= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert > Ak^{1/p})\\
    &= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[1\{\vert X \vert > Ak^{1/p}\}]\\
    &= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k = 1}^\infty 1\{\vert X \vert > A k^{1/p}\} \right]
    \end{align*}
$$
Here, the swap between the sum and integral can be justified by the monotone convergence theorem. Now, since $X \in L^p$, we have $\vert X \vert^p < \infty$ a.s, therefore,
$$
    \sum_{k = 1}^\infty 1\{\vert X \vert > Ak^{1/p}\} = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty 1\left\{k < \dfrac{\vert X \vert^p}{A^p}\right\} \le \dfrac{\vert X\vert^p}{A^p} \text{ a.s}
$$
Therefore,
$$
    \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\vert Y_k \vert > Ak^{1/p}) \le \dfrac{1}{A^p} \mathbb{E}(\vert X \vert^p) < \infty
$$
For the third condition, that is,
$$
    \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \text{Var}\left(\dfrac{Y_k}{k^{1/p}}1\left\{\dfrac{\vert Y_k \vert}{k^{1/p}} \le A\right\}\right) < \infty
$$
This is a direct application of the following lemma, the proof of this, I'll refer to Allan Gut's Probability: A Graduate Course:

Lemma 6.1 Let $0 < r < 2$. Suppose that $X, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are iid random variables, and set
$$
     Y_n = X_n 1\{\vert X_n \vert \le n^{1/r}\}, n \ge 1
$$
If $\mathbb{E}\vert X \vert^r < \infty$, then
$$
    \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \text{Var}\left(\dfrac{Y_n}{n^{1/r}}\right) < \infty
$$


for the first, i came to realize that it was really necessary just to observe that for $X \sim X_i^p$, $\sum \mathbb{P} (|X_i/n^{1/p}| > 1) = \mathbb{E}[ \sum 1 !!! 1 { |X| > n}]$ and that $ \sum 1 !!! 1 { |X| > n} = \lfloor |X| \rfloor$, which is obviously integrable if |X| is, as it is. Also we don't really need where $p$ is taken from.

For the second condition, note that $E[Y_n\mathbf{1}{Y_n\leq 1}]=E[Y_n\mathbf{1}{Y_n>1}]$, since $Y_n$ is centered. Bound the last term by the expectation of the absolute value, then switch the expectation and the series.
